# How to set a border on a SectionStackSection

Tags: smartgwt

In smartgwt, it is fairly easy to manipulate the border of the header or the content of a `SectionStackSection`, since they render seperate html elements.

However, is it also possible to set a border on the entire `SectionStackSection` as well? There is no surrounding div, and the section does nog have a `setBorder()` method.

Any ideas?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

You can use setAttribute(String property,String value) method to acheive this.

```
 SectionStackSection section1 = new SectionStackSection("Blue Pawn");
 section1.setExpanded(true);
 section1.addItem(new Img("pieces/48/pawn_blue.png", 48, 48));
 section1.setAttribute("border", "1px solid red");
 sectionStack.addSection(section1);
```